# How to lock builds on circleci

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

The idea is when 2-3 concurrent commits are pushed to a branch, it shouldn't start all build jobs for a given step in circleCI. It should wait until the 1st job is finished and then only run the next one in the queue. 
I have tried using the below links but no luck. Please help.
* https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/gastfreund/dynamo-lock?version=1.0.1
* https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/freighthub/lock

Comment: I have a similar use case. Were you able to finally solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/eddiewebb/queue#usage-examples as it seems quite robust, is still maintained and has pretty good documentation. It also lets you define a custom job and queue the entire workflow or just a specific job(s).